# Trouble with equation for tick in Wadler, »Monads for functional programming«, section 3

Tags: functional-programming, monads, state-monad

In Wadler's [Monads for functional programming](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) I'm looking at the equation

> *tick* ✭ λ().*m* = *m* ✭ λ().*tick*

in section 3 (in the context of State Monad). It is claimed that it

> holds so long as *tick* is the only action on state within *m*.

I fail to understand how this can be the case. Doesn't the left term have the type of *m* while the right term has the type of *tick* : *M* ()? Moreover, if the type of *m* isn't *M* (), the types of the operands of ✭ are mismatched on the right-hand side.

I looked around but couldn't find any errata, and the same equation appears in the revised version of the paper from 2001, so there must clearly be something I'm missing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell syntax,

```hs
tick x  =  ((), x+1)
unitState a x  =  (a, x)
bindState m k  =  uncurry k . m    -- StarOp for State

bindState tick (\() -> m) =
     = uncurry (\() -> m) . (\x -> ((), x+1))
     = (\y -> uncurry (\() -> m) ( (\x -> ((), x+1)) y))
     = (\y -> uncurry (\() -> m)          ((), y+1)    )
     = (\y ->         (\() -> m)           () (y+1)    )
     = (\y ->                 m               (y+1)    )

bindState m (\() -> tick) =
     = uncurry (\() -> tick) . m
     = uncurry (\() -> (\x -> ((), x+1))) . m
     = uncurry (\() x -> ((), x+1)) . m
     = (\y -> uncurry (\() x -> ((), x+1)) (m y))
     = (\y -> let ((),z) = m y in ((), z+1))
```

These two will only be the same if `m y` returns `((),z)` such that `m (y+1)` returns `((),z+1)` (i.e. `m y` only adds some *fixed amount* to the initial state `y`, which does not depend on `y`).

So I don't see the problem with the types, but that English phrase's meaning eludes me too.

By the way the paper's proposed way of adding "execution counts" to its monadic evaluator  by changing this `unitState` into `unitState a x  =  (a, x+1)`, essentially, would make it an illegal monad because this new `unitState` won't be an identity.

The types are,

```hs
tick :: M ()
bindState :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
(\() -> tick) :: () -> M () 

bindState (tick :: M ()) ((\() -> m) :: () -> M b ) :: M b
bindState (m :: M ()) ((\() -> tick) :: () -> M ()) :: M ()
```

So the only thing with the types is that `m` must be `m :: M ()`, not the general `M b`, as we already saw with the expansions above.

Comment: Thanks for working that out! It confirms my suspicion that the identity only holds for `m :: M ()`, as you say, so in particular not in the setting of section 2.8 where _m_ = _unit_ (_a_ ÷ _b_).

As for your other comment, my interpretation of "replace _unit_ (_a_ ÷ _b_)" by the given equation refers to the program code in section 2.5, not to the definition of _unit_.